# Symfony 2 site on the remote server (Apache). Error 403

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I added my Symfony (2.7) site on the remote server and received 403 error for all pages (/web/app.php, /web/app_dev.php and other).
Another sites (non-Symfony) haven't this problem.

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

**.htaccess**

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**Permissions for site folder:**

drwxr-x---  8 daria www-data

**Permissions for web folder**

drwxr-x---  4 daria www-data

**Permissions for app folder**

drwxr-x---  6 daria www-data

Apache configuration file (in **/etc/apache2/sites-available**)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin ***@gmail.com
     ServerName urltest.cu.cc
     ServerAlias www.urltest.cu.cc
     DocumentRoot /var/www/urltest.cu.cc/web
     DirectoryIndex app.php
     <Directory /var/www/urltest.cu.cc/web>
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted

      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
      </IfModule>
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I would try these two lines in VH configuration inside `<Directory>`:    ` Order Allow,Deny` and `Allow from All`